# Adding importrange to existing IFERROR(TEXT(MODE(ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKDAY(FILTER formula

Tags: date, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have this formula which does what I need to find the mode day within the filter.

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(MODE(ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKDAY(FILTER(June!X$3:X,June!P$3:P=A3,June!X$3:X<>"")))),"dddd"))
```

I need the sheet 'June!' to sit within a different workbook because the dataset is so large. Therefore, I need to use import range within this same formula with URL,'June!' but I am not sure how to make this work.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY", "June!P3:X")}, 
 "select Col9 
  where Col1 = '"&A3&"' 
    and Col9 is not null", 0), "dddd"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TEXT(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY", "June!P3:X")}, 
 "select Col9 
  where Col1 = '"&A3&"' 
    and Col9 is not null", 0), "dddd"), "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc"), 2, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those seem to work, literally the cell stays blank. thank you for trying though

Comment: @Stuart can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: Data is on this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the other sheet I am trying to import result too is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1po7i3V2MItmIJtdVsVn9vPygcpY58oBJ-M8jEUT3U1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Stuart answer updated

Comment: I thought it was working but then I noticed the results aren't pulling the mode day but instead are for some reason just returning the days. When I tried it on my live data, it is also returning random days amongst the data too.

I'm thinking Mode needs to be added back in somehow but also the days that I switched in original formula ie. 1, Sunday may be a different default set in this new query but I'm not sure

Comment: @Stuart answer updated

Comment: Perfect, it does exactly what I need it too. Just trying to figure out how now ;)